# How to get iTerm's Semantic History working with line and column number

Tags: pycharm, iterm2

Here is the output I'm working with:

```
************* Module happymoose.utils.template_filters
happymoose/utils/template_filters.py:10:0: W0611: Unused markdown imported from markdown (unused-import)
```

I have setup my iTerm's semantic history feature so when I Cmd+click a line, it will open up the correct file in my editor. However, the line number doesn't seem to be applied.

Here is the command I am using:
`/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm  \1 --line \2`

And here is the preference settings. [image: iTerm Advanced Preference - Semantic History]

I'm on iTerm2 Build 3.3.6 and latest build of Catalina.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think I've found out what's causing the problem. It turns out that the command line `/usr/local/bin/charm` on my Mac was pointing to an old version PyCharm:

```
$ grep PATH /usr/local/bin/charm
RUN_PATH = u'/Applications/PyCharm.app'
CONFIG_PATH = u'/Users/alexdong/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2016.3'
SYSTEM_PATH = u'/Users/alexdong/Library/Caches/PyCharm2016.3'
```

It turns out that I'm actually on PyCharm2019.3. So after I manually changed the `/usr/local/bin/charm` so it points to `/Users/alexdong/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2019.3`, the Semantic History started to work beautifully.

I hope this helps to put smile on someone's face. Enjoy!